# Escaping partial with assemble

Tags: gruntjs, templating, handlebars.js, assemble

I have a partial which is a comment-entry. I use this to render all known comments, to the partial contains fields like `{{byUser}}` and so forth.

When a user posts a new comment, I want to use the Handlebars.js templating, and use the same partial, but this time I don't want [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) to try to convert the double-brackets to data, but just output the partial as defined.

I tried to tripple-stash `{{{}}}` the partial, but it doesn't work.

I can't tripple-stash the content of the partial, because I use it as a "normal" partial for old comments.

What to do?

Answer (score 3):

Add backslash `\` before opening tag.

```
\{{}}
```

Comment: I wanted to escape a partial `{{>partial}}` not just a data key.

Comment: Yes. It should have no problem. `\{{>partial}}`

Comment: @KennethB Assemble uses handlebars as the template engine, so the syntax is handlebars. @Hariadi is 100% correct. Doing `\{{> foo }}` does work. (I know b/c I've done it at least 1,000 times in the Assemble docs ;-) Handlebars recently started allowing quadruple staches for escaping, so `{{{{> foo }}}}` should work as well. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @jonschinkert & Hariadi Is there any larger scale way to do this other than replacing each variable with the \{{}}? Like a way to include a partial that doesn't parse anything?